# One user unable to connect to non-domain joined computers

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

On Wednesday, I lost RDP access to all non-domain-joined computers (Windows OS) from my Windows 11 laptop at work. It only affects my local user profile. I can sign in with a different domain account on my laptop and the RDCs work. I can also connect to those computers from another laptop logged in with my credentials.

Before I delete my local profile, is there anything I could check? I've been through the firewall (turned it off), antivirus, GPol. Nothing sticks out.

The error code is 0x204, which I think has to do with NLA. I've enabled and disabled it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply delete the profile, it's not hard to bring back the data, just copy your old profile's folder before removing the profile. A lot less work necessary than trying to find what registry setting in your HCU block you.